# How do you scale a square image without losing the aspect ratio (even if the layout is not square)

Tags: android, layout, image-scaling

I'd like to create a square layout so I could scale up/and down a square image I have - using 'android:scaleType="fitXY"'.
Other scale types don't work because they don't scale up the image.

The problem is that I can't create an exact square layout.
In order for the scaling up to work, I need to give a very big width/height (like 150dp * 150dp).

Sometimes, the image is found within another layout, which it's size I don't know.
If the width/height of the layout is smaller than 150dp, the whole layout is filled and the image loses it's aspect ratio.

How do you scale up and down a square image without losing the aspect ratio?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

```
ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_CROP
```

Comment: Cropping does not keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: I think that's what you are looking for. Did you give it a try?